# android: adding horizontal line to layout makes it empty

Tags: android, layout, view, border, rulers

adding this to my layout returns an empty layout after I inflate it and add it to another view

```
  <View 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="1px" 
  android:background="#e0e0e0"/>
```

here's how I inflate it

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.stoplistitem, null);
if(dt != null && stop.getDescription() != null)
    dt.setText(stop.getDescription());
if(st != null && stop.getStreet() != null)
    st.setText(stop.getStreet());
if(mt != null && stop.getMunicipal() != null)
    mt.setText(stop.getMunicipal());
if(idt != null && stop.getId() != null){
    idt.setText(stop.getId().toString());
```

//edit I can see the view, but there is no content

Comment: the code you have posted is still not enough to understand how you are adding line video to main layout.

Comment: it's just in the root LinearLayout followed by 4 EditTexts

Answer (score 0):

Attach this view to a ViewGroup while inflating by using `inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)` and attachToRoot = true, root is the component on which you want to inflate

Comment: so the root has to be the view I want to put my new view in right?